# HTML ui/li button form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I'm trying to create dynamic button with selector and what I'll select in the button drop down will be submitted to the next page. However it doesn't work I can't retrieve whatever was selected in the button's. What is the right way to submit such data in a form?

I'm submitting the form to php page while getting it using $_POST["packageType"], found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853563/how-do-i-submit-a-form-with-a-li-instead-of-a-submit-button) the following approach:

```
onclick="myForm.myVariable.value='foo';myForm.submit();"
```

Is it legit or there is better way to do such dynamic value submission?

[image]

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" id="1111">
<input id="packageType" type="hidden" name="packageType" value="N/A"/>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add Plan</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu package-selector" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="1111.packageType.value='basic';1111.submit();">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="1111.packageType.value='premium';1111.submit();">Type 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Javascript or php to get the value being passed to the next page and how are you passing it? The more relevant information you can give the easier it will be for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it quickly, your solution could work (as long as your bootstrap code is set up correctly). There is just an issue with how you reference your form "1111".

Try rewriting your ul / li tags like that

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu package-selector" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('1111').packageType.value='basic';document.getElementById('1111').submit();">Type 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('1111').packageType.value='premium';document.getElementById('1111').submit();">Type 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

The `document.getElementById('1111')` search for the form and references it. JavaScript does not understand `1111` directly.

There are some other ways to reference the form. For instance `document.forms[0]` but, since you have an `id` attribute in your form, that's the simplest way.

As a side note: I would recommend not using ids starting with numbers (for instance, replace `1111` by `myform1111` or similar).